# Can having spaces in the Android SDK path cause problems in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, sdk

I have installed my Android SDK to the default path on a Windows 7 PC, i.e.:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

I specify the location of my SDK in Eclipse, but it forgets it every time Eclipse is launched with a new sample project.

**Edit**: Also, sometimes the emulator refuses to run from within Eclipse.

I was wondering if having spaces in the file name `..Program Files (x86)..` is causing the problems. And if that's the case, is there any way to change the directory location (move the SDK files) of an already installed Android SDK? (I guess it involves changing some 10-15 registry entries) or should I re-install all of it, which I don't want to do (cause it takes forever to download the SDK and all its components on my connection).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could post an answer as an addendum, and yes .. mentioning it in your question would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android SDK path remains der for a particular Workspace and not depend on the project you create. If you change the eclipse workspace you have to again set the location of Android SDK for that workspace.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Having spaces in the android path is not the cause of eclipse forgetting the android sdk location, if eclipse work space directory is changed, sdk location has to be provided again.

As far as emulator is concerned, It does not start sometimes when your sdk installation path has spaces like this

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

solution to this problem is to change the android sdk location in eclipse ( Window > Prefrences > Android) to

C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk

then the problem is resolved,

Answer (score 1):

Its the same path on my Windows 7 including spaces. There is no problem with it.