# android emulator forever launching

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, boot

i want to set up an android emulator, i downloaded android 4.4 (kitkat), tools, and all the extra's

the emulator is loading forever, its already loading for 2 hours, the android startup boot logo is not laggy, so the emulator is not slow.

I rebooted multiple times, and tried different devices

my emulator:
device:  10.1" WGXA (tablet) (1280 x 800: mdpi)
Target:  android 4.4 - API level 19
CPU:     ARM (armeabi-v7a)        <--- cant change this
Memory Options:  RAM:768 VM Heap: 32
Internal storage:  4096
Emulation Options:  use host GPU

Computer specs:
4.2GHz 8-core cpu
4GB ram
and lot more

if i look in task manager it is using 15%cpu, 470MB RAM and 0MB disk speed

Answer (score 4):

when you're using the Windows OS, you have to set the RAM to 512Mb in order to get the AVD to run properly.
Hope this helps as 2 hours is an awful long time for the emulator to load.

Comment: Need to increase VM heap size to 512. It's different from RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, try starting the AVD on its own and wipe user data before trying your app.

Comment: I tried starting the AVD on its own , this didnt helps !
What do u mean by **wipe** ?

Comment: If you launch `android avd`, select a device and click `Start`, it should show a settings screen before start with a checkbox that says `Wipe user data`. For me this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are running these settings
10.1" WGXA (tablet) (1280 x 800: mdpi)
CPU: ARM (armeabi-v7a)
use host GPU

you must have a SUPER COMPUTER.... try a lower resulion start with 800x400, 
if you have an INTEL pc, 
download the "INTEL" engine from the SDK-MANAGER.API19
then use "use the GPU" setting and choose the "engine: intel" setting when creating an emulator

if you have a non-intel, then im sorry, stick with 800x400 resolution

Answer (score 0):

Open android sdk manager

Extras-> install Android Support library

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem on Windows 8 64-bit, with fresh installation of Eclipse and Android SDK - Virtual device was starting "forever". 
I found this thread http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=android+emulator+forever+launching and link to
[Can having spaces in the android sdk path cause problems in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401424/can-having-spaces-in-the-android-sdk-path-cause-problems-in-eclipse)

**Solution:** I moved Android SDK from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`

to

`c:\android-sdk`

Changed location in Eclipse, and this fixed a problem for me. Now AVD launches normally. I have not found any other comments on the reason or explanation.

I hope it will help someone else.