# Android 4.4 Virtual Device Internal Storage Will Not Resize

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device, internal-storage

When creating a new Android 4.4 Virtual Device using the AVD Manager, I cannot get the internal storage to be anything larger than 200MB.

512MB is the internal storage size I would like to set.

I've tried:

- Setting the internal storage of the device in the AVD Manager to 512MB.
- In Eclipse project Debug Configurations, under the Target tab, setting Additional Emulator Command Line Options to -partition-size 512.
- In the Eclipse Preferences, under Android, I set the Default emulator options to -partition-size 512.
- Editing the config file for my virtual device under (User)/.android/avd/(device).avd/config.ini

  - Then setting disk.dataPartition.size to disk.dataPartition.size=512M
  - Also tried setting it to disk.dataPartition.size=512MB
  - Also tried setting it to data.dataPartition.size=512M

This happens on both ARM and Intel Atom x86 CPUs.

Now when I switch over to Android 3.0 (ARM), I can resize it simply using the AVD Manager to my hearts content. Is there an issue with Android 4.4? Is there something I missed? Or a possible work around?

Comment: The following Android issue is open for this bug. Current status as of 9/15/2014 is assigned / triaged. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75141

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Now that the emulator file system is ext4 I was able to re-size the `userdata.img` using standard Linux tools.

```
# Navigate to AVD
cd ~/.android/avd/Nexus5
# Delete old image
rm userdata-qemu.*
# Re-size the image
resize2fs userdata.img 512M
# Start the emulator and enjoy
emulator @Nexus5
```

**Edit**
I was also able to re-size `userdata-qemu.img` directly but I had to run `e2fsck` first.

```
 e2fsck -f userdata-qemu.img
 resize2fs userdata-qemu.img 512M
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only way that will work for me. I have to switch into Linux, do this, then switch back into Windows. It's quite a pain.

Comment: There is a e2fsprogs package available for Cygwin.  Maybe there is a MinGW port.

Comment: On Mac OS X you can use `brew install e2fsprogs` when using the homebrew package manager to install these tools. Since they are not being symlinked to `/usr/local` by default, you should use their full path to run them, e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/e2fsprogs/1.42.9/sbin/resize2fs`.

Comment: I used the above mentioned commands but now my emulator wont boot :(

Comment: This, combined with the tune2fs answer below worked, then got my emulator to boot again!

Comment: Same as Matt, I used this and the tune2fs and it worked just fine. The only thing I had to resize both userdata-qemu.img and also userdata.img.

Comment: One thing - choose to fix any FS errors if e2fsck reports them...then run tune2fs

Comment: great workaround! it worked on mac. Thanks also to  nerdinand to poiting out how to install the missing command for mac.

Comment: `Edit` part of answer didn't work for me since it modifies `userdata-qemu.img` and not `userdata.img` (the first one did nothing for my AVD). Also: given tools are available in SDK as of september'17, they are in `${MY_SDK_DIR}/emulator/bin64/` folder

Comment: Also check for this line `disk.dataPartition.size=...` in `config.ini` and make sure it's `disk.dataPartition.size=512M` instead of something else. I created it with a 2048MB config in AS UI and it was created with `disk.dataPartition.size=2G` instead of `disk.dataPartition.size=2048M` and it wouldn't work

Answer (score 29):

Even above suggestion can cause to android emulator hang on boot logo. The reason is that resize2fs do the changes thats are right in general but considered as broken fs by android and prevent it to mount it in rw mode, that hangs up the boot process.

Examening boot logs shows something like that:

```
EXT4-fs error (device mtdblock1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:741: group 2, 32366 clusters in bitmap, 32370 in gd
```

Event e2fsck does not fix it for android and to workaround it i use tune2fs to change the way how android should continue to mount broken fs.

```
tune2fs -e continue userdata-qemu.img
```

Comment: Thanks, this in combination with the accepted answer above worked for me!

Comment: Yeah, I had to do this to get the emulator to boot past the Android boot logo.

Comment: Brilliant! combined with the answer worked for me. Without tun2fs sim was stuck in Android boot image.

Answer (score 5):

Someone13, this is definitely a Bug in Target: "Android 4.4.2 - API Level 19"

I have the same problem- can’t change the size of internal storage of the device in emulator of Android SDK by no way(even with “disk.dataPartition.size=xxxM” in config.ini or with command-prompt arguments “-partition-size xxx”) when using Android 4.4.2 in the Emulator of Android SDK.

The only way is to set custom size is when using as Target: Android 3.0 - API Level 11.

My hardware: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, RAM 4GB; Core Duo 2.28GHz; GT630

Answer (score 4):

If you are still having this issue in 2016, try deleting the image from AVD manager, and then add back the emulator.

It seemed like I could not resize the emulator no matter what I do, but it worked when I deleted the image and then recreated image with 1GB internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create this virtual device, maybe change your device type or something?

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me. I used that exact same setup that you displayed in the pic. I also tried updating my Android Developer Tools and updated 4.4 to 4.4.2. Still same issues.

Comment: @Someone13 Have you updated tiy sdk manager as well? Download the latest version and test it out.

Answer (score 1):

To build up on @Frohnzie's answer, resize2fs and e2fsck are now included in the [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) (you may need to update your SDK tools to see them) so you don't need to install them separately. They are located under *yourAndroidSDKFolder*/tools/bin (Windows, Linux) or *yourAndroidSDKFolder*/tools/bin64 (Mac, Linux).

Comment: Not sure why this answer had a downvote. +1, worked for me. Here's an example (with Android SDK installed by Xamarin): `~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/emulator/bin64/resize2fs ~/.android/avd/avdname.avd/userdata.img 1024M`. That's the only command you need if you run after `avd create`, but before launching the emulator for the first time.

Comment: Path in the anwer is incorrect @NateCook comment helped me to find resize2fs

Comment: If you can't find resize2fs, you may also be able to install via homebrew `brew install e2fsprogs`. More info on that approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579606/android-4-4-virtual-device-internal-storage-will-not-resize/23578503#comment34602627_20762411

Answer (score 0):

**Assaf G.'s** answer is good. But i have noticed in the following links in the first one user is able to create `Emulator` with **internal storage** `500MB`. But he is getting some `exceptions` but not related to **internal storage**.
And in the other link user able to create `emulator` with **internal memory** `4096MB`. But he is facing speed problems. So i think you have to try with **specifications** provided in first link.

1.[Android 4.4 Emulator](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62134)

2.[android emulator forever launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822853/android-emulator-forever-launching)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue when I accidentally chose the AOSP 4.4.2 emulator in Android Studio. The Google Inc. x86 emulator (below) doesn't seem to have this bug.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

delete /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files will release 200M+

Answer (score 0):

Here, there seems to be some catch, in older android tools lower than version 22, this does not work. I upgraded the android tools to 23 and this started working.

My configuration was
API Level 21
CPU: Intel X86
OS: Ubuntu Linux