# Android 4.4.2 emulator storage issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am searching to find  a solution for this issue for a while.I am trying to run my new app created using Cordova and sencha touch in android simulator .As there are a lot of resources  locally the APK size is a bit large (Around 197Mb).Now the issue is like wwhile running the app on simulator I am getting an error message "INSUFFIECIENT_STORAGE" and the app is no longer installing.I tried setting the partition size to 1024 as per some blogs ,but still the issue is there.Aslo when I tried to run the app on lower versions it is working fine.The issue is only with 4.4.2 version.Is it a bug in emulator ..How can I get around this issue ..Please advice

I am setting the internal storage and SD card size to 512 Mib and target is 4.4.2 .

Looking forward for a solution..Thanks in advance

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579606/android-4-4-virtual-device-internal-storage-will-not-resize