# Can Not Increase Android Emulator Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can't increase android emulator internal storage more than 533 MB even I already tried:

1. Edit disk.dataPartition.size=1G in config.ini file
2. change the configuration on Android Virtual Device Manager like screen shoot below.

But the android emulator internal storage still 533 MB

[image]
My setting for emulator

1. android studio 1.3.1
2. Nexus 5 emulator profie
3. Target sdk 5.1.1
4. cpu x86_64

Comment: Please check this post, the answer there worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579606/android-4-4-virtual-device-internal-storage-will-not-resize

Comment: @turkenh is there any other way if using windows ?

Answer (score 9):

You can resolve this resizing the *userdata.img* file located on your avd emulator folder:

```
cd ~/.android/avd/yourEmulatorName
e2fsck -f userdata-qemu.img
rm userdata-qemu.*
resize2fs userdata.img 1024M
```

Now start your avd emulator again and you'll see that it's storage was increased. Windows users can do this with **Cygwin** enabling the *"e2fsprogs"* package on install/update.

> P.S.: You must change 1024M to your wanted value of internal storage.

#### UPDATE


The *e2fsck* is not really necessary, as pointed on comments by **@BoD**.

So all you need to increase the internal storage is run two commands on your target emulator folder.

In other words, you must:

1. Delete the old emulator images
2. Resize the userdata image file to wanted value

```
cd ~/.android/avd/yourEmulatorName
rm userdata-qemu.*
resize2fs userdata.img 1024M
```

Comment: Not sure why `e2fsck` is needed since we `rm` the file right after that... But this totally worked :)   Thanks!

Comment: @BoD Updated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

I tried many time to increase internal storage of an existing avd but didn't succeeded, the answer: delete the current avd and set the internal storage while creating it

Comment: This was finally the answer, which solved the problem for me. I was struggling around for hours.