# Can't resize android emulator internal storage through AVD, config.ini, or resize2fs

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep running out of storage space when I work on my app for a long time. I'm assuming it's because the emulator is incorrectly uninstalling the old apks?

Internal storage is always stuck at 541MB, even if I change the settings in AVD. The settings in config.ini are correctly set and I see `disk.dataPartition.size=2000M`.

I've tried wiping and restarting the emulator, creating other virtual devices, and even resize2fs detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20762411/2532762

Nothing seems to work. I've tried API 22 & 23 emulators. Both x86

Comment: Why don't you just create a new emulator?

Comment: I do. any emulator I make is locked to 541MB

Comment: What is your system configurations?

Comment: 480x800 device, api 22, google apis, x86, ram: 1536 MB, vm heap:128MB, internal storage: 2000MB, SD card: studio managed 400MB

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial to increase internal storage of your Android emulator by using SDK Manager :

https://myworks2012.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/android-emulator-internal-storage-configuation/

I hope it will be helpful for you